# Is it possible to use a wildcard ssl certificate for code signing?

Tags: ssl, certificate, digital-signature

I have a wildcard certificate for my company (*.mycompany.com) and now got the task to digitally sign an installer executable.
I use Signtool.exe with a generated pfx file containing private key and certificate files (including the intermediate certificate), however it always tells me that no certificate meets all the given criteria. (In the debug output I can see that the wildcard certificate gets filtered by the EKU filter and the intermediate and root certificates are filtered by the private key filter).

The windows certificate manager says that the wildcard certificate can only be used for server and client authentication. I can't add Code Signing to the purposes, which the intermediate certificate has.

Is it at all possible to use this wildcard certificate for code signing? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your certificate does not have Code Signing EKU as you have already figured out. Without it you can not sign your executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always possible to use the key if you got access to the key. But in that case the code used for signing must be told to ignore the extended key usage. And - more problematic - the verification procedure must also skip this check.

But since your certificate misses the *extended key usage* for code signing, and since extended key usage is present, the following part of the [X.509 v3 certificate specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12) is in effect:

> If the extension is present, then the certificate MUST only be used
> for one of the purposes indicated.  If multiple purposes are
> indicated the application need not recognize all purposes indicated,
> as long as the intended purpose is present.  Certificate using
> applications MAY require that the extended key usage extension be
> present and that a particular purpose be indicated in order for the
> certificate to be acceptable to that application.

Now as `id-kp-serverAuth` is probably present, and since `id-kp-codeSigning` isn't, the certificate cannot be used.

As these extensions are *signed* by the certificate authority you cannot simply change the certificate. If you do change the extended key usage then verification of the signature within the certificate will fail.

---

Note that usually keys and certificates are *single purpose*. If you need a code signing certificate you may have to create a new key pair & certificate request to buy a new certificate.

Comment: Thanks. I did indeed end up buying a new certificate which worked great :)